# Dhitools plot_item results in python failure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using dhitools developed by robjameswall for reading and plotting DHI's Mike files (i.e DFSU). My code is as follows:

```
modelpath = 'xxx.dfsu'
area = dhitools.dfsu.Dfsu(modelpath)
fig,ax,tf = area.plot_item(item_name= 'Total SSC', tstep=1)
plt.show()
```

The code fails at the plot_item line. There is no error message, it just shows that the kernal have died (i am using jupyter) and python is not working properly. Any ideas what is happening? I am following the instructions provided by the author here: https://github.com/robjameswall/dhitools/blob/master/notebooks/dfsu_analysis.ipynb

If any one has experience using this module, please let me know.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

An update on my question. I realized that it works perfectly fine when working with HD files (items include surface elevation, water depth, current speed, etc.). Example of the plot produced below:[image]

However, the problem arises when i am processing MT files (item == Total Suspended Solids (SSC) in mg/L units). Python fails to run. I believe this should be an issue with the dfsu.py script which uses matplotlib triplot and tricontourf.